# use of the definite article the

Tags: articles

When a noun is used second time it is preceded by the definite article the.As - I saw a dog. The dog was black. But when an uncountable noun is used in general should it be preceded by' the' in second time as- Maxican food is very spicy. The food tastes very hard.Or food tastes very hard.

Comment: In English, we don't usually say food tastes *hard*.  We might say it is *hard* (or difficult) *to eat*, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *the* in this case too: *the food*.

It doesn't matter if the noun is countable or uncountable. What matters is if it's definite or indefinite. If you refer to something/somebody mentioned before, use *the*:

- I see a man. *The* man is old.
- There is some water in the glass. *The* water is cold.